# how to write updated data records in Pyspark Streaming?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Hi I am learning Pyspark and so was working on a personal Project I am readStreaming from kafka and want to write to MongoDB (Database can change as this is personal project only). My use case is this .

data 1 :   `1 , spark , 99`

Collection

```
1,spark,99
```

data 2 :   `2 , Kafka, 100`

Collection

```
1,spark,99
2,Kafka,100
```

data 3: `1 , spark , 120`

Collection

```
1,spark,120
2,Kafka,100
```

here I want this data document to replace 1,spark,99 to 1,spark,120 based on first value which 1 same for both.

This is basically to have updated value of that particular record as data comes.

As I am using MongoDB I was not able to use writeStream directly through forEachBatch only i am able to write this data though i am stuck to implement my scenario.

Comment: Can you share your code as a [mcve]? Also, MongoDB isn't a table, so I don't understand this CSV format, but do you really need Spark?  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/fundamentals/write-strategies/#replace-one-business-key-strategy